# can I deduce a tuple element type in a function parameter (ie with std::tuple_element)?

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I have a struct which stores some data in a tuple. I want to build a function `getWithDefault<n>(m)`, which gets the data from the nth term but replaces it with m if the value is 0. But to do this, I have to know the correct data type for m in the function parameter: `getWithDefault<>(WhichType?)`. Is there any way of doing this? I've tried with `std::tuple_element`, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>


template <typename... T>
struct C
{
    C(T... args) : t(std::make_tuple(args...)) {}

    template <int n>
    auto get() const
    { return std::get<n>(t); }

    template <int n>
    auto getWithDefault(std::tuple_element<n, decltype(t)>::type de)    // Compiler error: identifier not found
    {
        const auto v = get<n>();
        return v != 0 ? v : de;
    }

private:

    const std::tuple<T...> t;
};



int main()
{

    C<int, int> c(0, 4);

    std::cout << c.getWithDefault<0>(5);     // this should return 5

    return 0;
}
```

I can see why this code fails--`std::tuple_element` doesn't have access to the member variable from inside the function parameter. So, is there a viable way of deducing the type of a tuple term from within a function parameter?

Comment: why do you want to deduce something? The type of the tuple is just `std::tuple<T...>`, no?

Comment: I want the type of an *element* of the tuple, not the tuple itself.

Comment: yes, but the type is known, no need to deduce

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to deduce the type, because you already know it. Maybe you refer to using `decltype`, but you also do not need that (you can, but need not). Anyhow...

For convenience you can use an alias template:

```
template <size_t n>
using nth_type = typename std::tuple_element<n,std::tuple<T...>>::type;
```

[Full example:](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VqxkJWUrKNZhfOAV)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>


template <typename... T>
struct C
{
    C(T... args) : t(std::make_tuple(args...)) {}


    template <size_t n>
    using nth_type = typename std::tuple_element<n,std::tuple<T...>>::type;
    template <int n>
    auto get() const
    { return std::get<n>(t); }

    template <size_t n>
    auto getWithDefault(nth_type<n> de)    
    {
        const auto v = get<n>();
        return v != 0 ? v : de;
    }

private:

    const std::tuple<T...> t;
};



int main()
{

    C<int, int> c(0, 4);

    std::cout << c.getWithDefault<0>(5);     // this should return 5

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: tbh I didnt know what exactly was the problem with code in question before I read the other answer and now stealing it just to improve my answer wouldn't be kind

Answer (score 1):

You just have order of declaration issue (and a missing `typename`), move `t` before `getWithDefault`:

```
template <typename... T>
struct C
{
private:
    const std::tuple<T...> t;

public:
    C(T... args) : t(std::make_tuple(args...)) {}

    template <int n>
    auto get() const
    { return std::get<n>(t); }

    template <int n>
    auto getWithDefault(std::tuple_element_t<n, decltype(t)> de)
    {
        const auto v = get<n>();
        return v != 0 ? v : de;
    }

};
```

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3107c9835aeb48f9)

Comment: Compile in C++17 in gcc/clang/msvc [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eYBUNy).